# Document wide onclick event send form data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple page for users to purchase email subscriptions.  They enter a desired username which is validated with jquery, and then one other piece of data.

There are then 2 buttons, one for pay with Bitcoin, the other with paypal.

What I'd like to do is capture an onclick event when either of those buttons are clicked and send me an email with the the user information from the form so the address can then be setup.

Is this possible or is there a better way?  What I don't want is for the user to have to click the submit button to send the email without having to go through one of the payment options.

I was hoping to grab that click event, send the email, then the user goes goes on to pay as normal depending on which link is chosen.  The other piece of info is that the BC payment button is just an  link, the paypal one is a form.

Can I just do something like:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
document.addEventListener('click',
    function () {
        // handle event here
    },
    false
);
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
document.attachEvent('onclick',
    function () {
        // handle event here
    }
);
}
```

Will that successfully grab either click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery, you can do something like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("body").on("click", function(){
          // handle your event here
     });
 });
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Is there any benefit/drawback to using body over say $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#content').click(function(e) {  
        alert(1);
    });
});
Alternatively, try using .live

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#content').live('click', function(e) {  
        alert(1);
    });
});

Comment: The former case will handle the click event of the element with an id _#content_, not the whole page which is I think you want. About _.live_, it is deprecated after Jquery 1.7. More info about event handlers **[HERE](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)**.